# Error on adding code in app.run() function in the program.cs file in .net 6 core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm trying to convert a console app into a .net6 core Web Api app and for that, I made some changes in the program.cs file too.
Everything goes perfectly but when I try to print our a line using:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("string");
```

I get an error in the .exe window that pops up.

> **warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[2]
> The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed. fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HMGA3IKGSA02", Request id "0HMGA3IKGSA02:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
> application.
> System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String
> value)**

This is the entire code I have written in the program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hell");
    await next();
});

app.Run();
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn’t call the `next.Invoke` after we
send the response to the client. This can cause exceptions if we try to set
the status code or modify the headers of the response.
Your code says that

> System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has
> already started.